# Creating google cloud endpoint V2 using android studio

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am using android studio to generate a google cloud endpoint project.
The issue is that my android studio (updated to version 2.x.x, and my SDK also up-to-date) is generating the project with endpoints V1 which is no longer supported.

Is there a way to generate a v2 project using android studio?
Or i should use another IDE? I went with the studio approach since it generated many of the files and annotations in an easy way.